# Proof statement for binary relation or show it is wrong by counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, relations

## Proof or show following statement is false

$$ (R \circ S) \cap (R \circ T) \subseteq R \circ (S \cap T) $$

## Statement is false by counterexample

Let $ \langle x,y \rangle \in (R \circ S) \cap (R \circ T) $

$$ \iff (\langle x, y \rangle \in R \circ S) \wedge (\langle x ,y \rangle \in R \circ T) $$

$$ \iff (\exists w: \langle w,y \rangle \in S) \wedge (\exists z : \langle z, y \rangle \in T) $$

$$ \iff \{ \langle x, w \rangle, \langle x, z \rangle  \} \in R $$

$$ \iff \{ \langle w, y \rangle \} \cap \{ \langle z , y \rangle \} = S \cap T = \emptyset $$

$$ \iff \langle x , y \rangle \not\in R \circ (S \cap T) $$

$$ \iff (R \circ S) \cap (R \circ T) \not\subseteq R \circ (S \cap T) $$

---

Is this valid?

Comment: What is your counterexample? And are you sure that what you connect by "$\iff$" is in each case equivalent?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No i'm not sure about that

Comment: It isn't a counterexample.  A counterexample is a specific example where the statement isn't true.  As far as your reasoning goes, I don't see how you suddenly decide $S\cap T=\emptyset$

Comment: Well the intersection of that set would be empty since $\{ \langle w , y \rangle \} \cap \{ \langle z, y \rangle \}$ would be empty right? They don't have a common item in the set.

Comment: It is highly likely that I'm completely lost with this, so maybe someone could show me how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be somehow on a right track, but what you write is formally awfully wrong. For example, the staements
$$ (\exists w: \langle w,y \rangle \in S) \wedge (\exists z : \langle z, y \rangle \in T)$$
and 
$$\{ \langle x, w \rangle, \langle x, z \rangle  \} \in R $$
are certainly not equivalent (the first says nothing about $R$, the second says nothing about $S,T$), hence should not be connected with an "$\iff$".

However, in the line where you end up writing $S\cap T=\emptyset$, you apparently have the right *idea*, namely to have $S=\{\langle w,y\rangle\}$ and $T=\{\langle z,y\rangle\}$ ... somehow.
Turn this into a *concrete* counterexample with all elements being different as far as required by the idea:

> Let $S=\{\langle 1,3\rangle\}$, $T=\{\langle 2,3\rangle\}$ and $R=\{\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 0,2\rangle\}$. Then
>   $$ R\circ S\cap R\circ T=\{\langle0,3\rangle\}\cap\{\langle0,3\rangle\}=\{\langle0,3\rangle\}$$
>   whereas $$ R\circ(S\cap T)=R\circ \emptyset=\emptyset.$$
>   Hence this $R,S,T$ make a counterexample to the given statement.

or somewhat "minimized":

> Let $S=\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}$, $T=\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$ and $R=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\}$. Then
>   $$ R\circ S\cap R\circ T=\{\langle0,1\rangle\}\cap\{\langle0,1\rangle\}=\{\langle0,1\rangle\}$$
>   whereas $$ R\circ(S\cap T)=R\circ \emptyset=\emptyset.$$

Comment: Excellent answer.  I was trying to write an answer along exactly the same lines, but couldn't find the phrasing.